# Pandas DataFrame set consecutive values to nan until value in column changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have the following DataFrame, where *Value* refers to my observations, and *Criterion* indicates, when a *Value* should be set to `np.nan`.

| Value | Criterion |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |

Whenever *Criterion* is equal to 1, I want to set the *Value* in the same row, as well as all consecutive *Value*s to zero until *Value* changes.
The desired output should look like this.

| Value | Criterion |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| nan | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| nan | 1 |
| nan | 0 |
| nan | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create groups by consecutive values in `Value` column and test if at least one `1` in `Criterion`, then set `NaN` per group in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
s = df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()

df['Value'] = df['Value'].mask(df['Criterion'].groupby(s).transform('any'))
print (df)
   Value  Criterion
0    3.0          0
1    3.0          0
2    NaN          1
3    7.0          0
4    2.0          0
5    2.0          0
6    NaN          1
7    NaN          0
8    NaN          0
9    1.0          0
```

Or if need test first value is `1` per consecutive groups in column `Criterion` use:

```
s= df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()

df['Value'] = df['Value'].mask(df['Criterion'].groupby(s).transform('first').eq(1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but your snippet also sets other duplicated values to zero. I've updated the sample dataframe to make this clear

Comment: @Michael - You are right, answer was changed by `mask` for set to `NaN` if `True`